# Stripe payment Android

Tags: php, android, stripe-payments, payment

I want to create payment using Stripe Api i created every thing in android and now i can get the token but he said send it to your server the problem that i can't find the server code or web service that will take my token and go pay with it any help please

https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android

```
    Card card = new Card("4242424242424242", 12, 2017, "123");

      Stripe stripe = new Stripe("pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh");
       stripe.createToken(
         card,
          new TokenCallback() {
            public void onSuccess(Token token) {
            // Send token to your server
              //what should i do in this step i want any code in php that do this job 
         }
           public void onError(Exception error) {
           // Show localized error message
           Toast.makeText(getContext(),
            error.getLocalizedString(getContext()),
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show();
            }
     }
    )
```

Comment: You need to do the payment in the server side of your system. What language are you using on your server side?

Comment: You have PHP examples here at Stripe: https://gist.github.com/1750375

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass token and other information to a php file:

```
<?php
  require_once('./config.php');

  $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => 'customer@example.com',
      'card'  => $token
  ));

  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => 5000,
      'currency' => 'usd'
  ));

  echo '<h1>Successfully charged $50.00!</h1>';
?>
```

Comment: How can I pass the token to the PHP file and where should I put this PHP file?

Comment: @IdoNaveh, In the above example I am using the $_POST method through a form. You can find a demo here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_method_post . You may put the php file anywhere you would like. You just have to tell your form where to send the action, which would be where you put this file. Or, if you are worried about Separation of Concern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), You may put the provided php inside the same file as your form is on, and leave the action of the form empty, then check for post to process it, as seen at w3school

Comment: @IdoNaveh , Here is another link: https://jsfiddle.net/g9e1qo3g/ this is a mock setup for what I was trying to describe for you. It may be of better help, but will most certainly need editing. Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know a lot of the POST method in android. Could you give me an example of how to send the token to the server using POST method?

Comment: Oh my apologies! I forgot this was on android. You will need this file on your server, without any html. You will send the request over http, this should be of help: http://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android

Comment: In the code, is the `$customer` is the person who pays or the person who gets the payment?

Comment: @IdoNaveh , When you access the Stripe SDK, your api keys are what designates who gets the money. The customer is just the customers, EI the person who is making the payment. You will never have to deal with account ownership on your end, unless you change the api keys to another stripe account.