# Get stripe payment status in android

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I have received the token id from stripe by providing card details.What I need to do with token id and how to get stripe payment status in android?

Using Token Id how can I know the successful payment status?What all are the details I need to send to server,where I have to use that Token whether I need to send it to server or stripe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripe payment Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568177/stripe-payment-android)

Answer (score 1):

You need to send that token to your server and use it to [create a Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/charges).